# Google OAuth 2: bad_request error on token request in windows store app

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, google-api, oauth-2.0, windows-store-apps

I am workin with google auth to access GMail from Windows Store App. I got success authorization code and now i'm trying to exchange it for an access code. I sent POST query as it described in Google Gide for installed apps:https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp.
 There is my POST query catched by feedler:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Length: 193
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

code=4/_ynXWYzGSols1p7lzuVBc59iGhgo& client_id={my client_id obtained during application registration}   &     client_secret={ my client secret obtained during application registration encoded by Uri.EscapeDataString()}& redirect_uri={ urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oobencoded by Uri.EscapeDataString()} & grant_type=authorization_code
```

The server returned "(400) Bad request".
 What is wrong in my request?

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `Uri.EscapeDataString()` on the values. If you look at the example at the page you linked to, they aren't escaped either.

Here's a code snippet that I'm using:

```
var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"code", authenticationCode},
        {"client_id", Keys.ClientId},
        {"client_secret", Keys.ClientSecret},
        {"redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"},
        {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
    };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form);

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", content);
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```